# Why can't I see the cursor?

Tags: installation, cursor

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer, which has an `AMD Sempron 3000+ 1.8 GHz CPU and 512 MB of RAM`, and I couldn't see my cursor. So I uninstalled it and then installed 11.10, but I still can't see my cursor, even after updates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of video graphics are you using? I had an ubuntu derivative once hide my mouse after a fresh install and not sure why, but by using a different graphics card instead of onboard graphics helped solved the problem.